# VBA Iterative Regression

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a code to perform a iterative regression analysis on a user defined set of data point from a larger set of data. The output is the R^2 value where another portion of my code will grab the maximum value and the indices where that value occurs. One of the issues I’m having with the iterative regression sequence is that the loop will only work for certain “sample_count” values depending on the length of the input data. Any help is appreciated as I have been staring at this for a while now.

```
Lastrow = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("I2:I" & Lastrow).Formula = "=$B$1*(G2/60)"
Range("J2:J" & Lastrow).Formula = "=($B$2*0.002)+I2"

sample_count = Application.InputBox("Please Enter       Number of Data Points to Consider for Linearity", , Type:=1)
Set r = Range("E2")
N = Range(r, r.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
i = 0: j = 0

Do While i + 2 * sample_count < N
Set rX = r.Offset(i, 4).Resize(sample_count, 1)
Set ry = r.Offset(i, 0).Resize(sample_count, 1)
rsquare = Application.WorksheetFunction.RSq(ry, rX)
r.Offset(j, 7).Value = rsquare
i = i + sample_count
j = j + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Your precise problem is not clear, to me at least. Can you be more specific please?

Comment: Say you have 1000 data points. I would like a regression to be performed iteratively on a user defined set of points (I.e 50 data points at a time A1:A50 then A51:A100, etc). Currently I can import a data set with ~750 points and select as low as 35 points to be analyzed, but nothing less. Interestingly, I can import a data set with ~1000 data points and only select as low as 75 data points to analyze. Maybe it’s the way my loop is counting, but I can’t seem to figure it out.

Comment: In each iteration of your loop rX and rY only offset by 1 so they will mostly overlap the previous ranges. Is that right?

Comment: Yes you are correct. It should be moving 50 points at a time so there isn’t overlap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the original ranges outside the loop and then you can just offset within the loop.

I'm not sure if there are other issues.

It's good practice to [declare your variables](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/declaringvariables.aspx).

```
Set rX = r.Offset(, 4).Resize(sample_count, 1) 'H3:H52
Set rY = r.Resize(sample_count, 1)

Do While i + 2 * sample_count < N
    rsquare = Application.WorksheetFunction.RSq(rY, rX)
    r.Offset(j, 7).Value = rsquare
    i = i + sample_count
    j = j + 1
    Set rX = rX.Offset(sample_count)
    Set rY = rY.Offset(sample_count)
Loop
```

Comment: Let me double-emphasize this point: `Option Explicit`!!  Let the compiler work for you – let it flush out "simple tpyos" for you.  Also, as SJR just did, "use indentation!"  Also:  "USE COMMENTS!  *TALK* TO YOURSELF!"  Use descriptive variable names. You will not(!) remember this stuff, even just a few days later.  Very soon (as right now ...) you'll be "puzzling out" _your own_ source code.  "Therefore, prepare for this as you write it the first time."

Comment: _Umm..._ "the above is the voice of **30+** years of experience," and yet I'm still doing this for a living and still having fun at it.  Go figure...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the way you're iterating is what's causing the issue. For instance, if I take parameters N=32 and my sample_count is 8 and analyze the loop using

```
Do While i + 2 * sample_count < N
    i = i + sample_count
    j = j + 1
    Debug.Print "@ iteration " & j & " i = " & i & vbCrLf; "i + 2 * sample_count = " & i + 2 * sample_count & " < " & N
Loop
```

I get

```
iteration 1 i = 8  
i + 2 * sample_count = 24 < 32  
iteration 2 i = 16  
i + 2 * sample_count = 32 < 32
```

So I only get 2 of my 4 sample groups. That being said, assuming you want to .Offset by the sample_count, I think you could effectively achieve what you're looking for by replacing your Do While-Loop with

```
For i = 0 To N Step sample_count
    Set rX = r.Offset(i, 4).Resize(sample_count, 1)
    Set ry = r.Offset(i, 0).Resize(sample_count, 1)
    rsquare = Application.WorksheetFunction.RSq(ry, rX)
    r.Offset(i + sample_count, 7).Value = rsquare
End Sub
```